# TFS Shelve vs DVCS (e.g Git, Mercurial) offline commits

Tags: git, mercurial, dvcs

While presenting DVCS concepts to my TFS-using co-workers, I was stumbled with the following questions:

> "How is these 'offline commits' are different than TFS shelving? I can
>   use it to backup my changes, rollback to a specific change and compare
>   my current changes to a shelved changeset."

The only answer I had is that TFS Shelving requires you to be connected to the central sever where is DVCS do not.

How would you answer that? What distinct advantage does DVCS' method of "local committing" have over TFS shelves?

Comment: To be honest, I love working with TFS but shelving is cumbersome. It's not what I expected it to be when I first used it and it looks like it's been added afterwards without providing decent access to it. It's hardly discoverable if you don't know where to look for it. You've already named one of the differences between shelving and the index. Another one would be that the index allows you to commit those [*aha fixes*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836801/git-should-i-ignore-the-index-or-is-there-a-killer-application-for-it) we have from time to time.

Comment: I haven't used TFS, only git. In git I usually have a long branch of local commits (at the moment I have a working directory with 18 local commits), I regularly edit the commits in the middle to keep related changes together and time to time I reorder some comments, usually accumulated bugfixes, to the bottom and push them to the shared repo while keeping the rest, which is work in progress, local. Can TFS shelving do this?

Comment: Team Foundation Version Control's idea of *shelvesets* are akin to *stashing* in git.  They lack the full fidelity of a commit.  (Also, since TFS supports git, we tend to talk about the centralized version control as "Team Foundation Version Control" while TFS is the overall system.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key difference is that DVCS offline commits are much more flexible. They allow you to prepare a whole series of changesets which you can then publish as a group in one go. You can also do some clever things with them, such as reordering them, combining them, splitting them apart, or even deleting some of them altogether. With TFS shelvesets, on the other hand, you are limited to working locally with only one changeset at a time.

Let's say you have made ten separate changes, numbered 1 to 10. In DVCS, you just check in after each change, then push to origin in a single operation once you're finished. With TFS, you end up with ten shelvesets, each of which contains the difference between your work and the latest version in the repository. They will look like this:

1. Change 1
2. Change 1 + change 2
3. Change 1 + change 2 + change 3

And so on.

This means that you can't just publish a series of changesets with a single command (as in `git push origin master`), you have to unshelve them one at a time then check them all in individually. That alone is cumbersome enough, but on top of that, the second and subsequent changesets will all give you merge conflicts because you are re-applying earlier changes which have already been applied.

Furthermore, your options for controlling which changes get published are severely limited. If you wanted to check in only changes 1, 2, 4, 6-8 and 10, omitting changes 3, 5 and 9, you couldn't do it. You couldn't reorder them either, nor could you squash a non-contiguous range of changes.

The upshot of this is that in TFS, even with shelving, it isn't practical to adhere to the best practice of checking in locally several times an hour, ensuring that every check-in makes only one change, and then tidying up before you publish your changes. The result will be a history consisting of larger, more bloated check-ins that are harder to understand and less useful if, for instance, you need to track down the revision that introduced a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Never used TFS, but I believe I get the gist.

The difference is that you can do the equivalent *locally*, e.g. on the plane. Set up branches for unfinished work, use tags to mark whatever points in the development you might want to refer to later. Can mix and match, compare current tip to another branch, to a previous tag on this branch, to a tag on another branch, any two tags, or even random commits you care to pick somehow. No need to plan ahead what would be useful "marks" on the development line. For a visual view of history `gitk` is a great help. A nice advantage is that nobody has to learn about your bumbling around and stupid experiments, all that is as private as you want. You can certainly set up remote repositories for backup purposes (not much more than `git` and `ssh` on the remote end are needed for this, and a bit of discipline to `git push` there with some regularity), and only send to the official, public repository what you want others to see.